# Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my simplified statement

```
SELECT ...
FROM tab1 AS i FULL OUTER JOIN tab2 AS d ON i.[Id]=d.[Id] 
WHERE d.[Data]<>i.[Data] OR 
    (d.[Data] IS NULL AND i.[Data] IS NOT NULL) OR 
    (d.[Data] IS NOT NULL AND i.[Data] IS NULL)
```

I want to get all entries that are

1. i.[Data] is different from d.[Data]
2. At least one value in table i or d is NOT NULL

So I don't want to see records were and i and d contain the same data or are both NULL.

My statement look so long and complicated. Is there an easier way?

Using `ISNULL(d.[Data],'')<>ISNULL(i.[Data],'')` works for text, but not for `DATE` or `TIME(0)` columns.

My statement works for every type.

Comment: You could use just constant of correct type in your second comparison - I think you should know your column type?

Comment: Unfortunately, they still haven't implemented the standard [`IS DISTINCT FROM`](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145-add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distin) which does exactly what you want in a single operator. But it's only been in the standard for two decades, so what can you expect..

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever See my answer and [Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In case you hadn't been aware of new developments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 4):

**Yes you can, and you can get the optimizer to recognize it too.**

[Paul White has this little ditty](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html):

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT d.[Data]
    INTERSECT
    SELECT i.[Data])
```

This works because of the semantics of `INTERSECT` which deal with nulls. What this says is "are there **no** rows in the subquery made up of value B and value B", this will only be satisfied if they are different values or one is null and the other not. If both are nulls, there will be a row with a null.

---

If you check the XML query plan (not the graphical one in SSMS), you will see that it compiles all the way down to `d.[Data] <> i.[Data]`, but the operator it uses will have `CompareOp="IS"` and not `EQ`.

See the full plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkhpBqZ-_).

The relevant part of the plan is:

```xml
                <Predicate>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="@t1.[i] as [t1].[i] = @t2.[i] as [t2].[i]">
                    <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Table="@t1" Alias="[t1]" Column="i" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Table="@t2" Alias="[t2]" Column="i" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </Predicate>
```

I find the optimizer works very well this way round, rather than doing `EXISTS / EXCEPT`.

---

**I urge you to vote for the [Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32889145-add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distin) to implement a proper operator.**

UPDATE FOR SQL SERVER 2022: This operator is now available as [`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: But this is not the solution and full query. So WHER d.[Data]<>i.[data] AND EXISTS (SELECT d.[Data] INTERSECT SELECT i.[Data]) correct?

Comment: No, you can leave out the first part of that, the `EXISTS` will do the whole comparison. have clarified

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify to:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE d.[Data] <> i.[Data]
OR IIF(d.[Data] IS NULL, 0, 1) = IIF(i.[Data] IS NULL, 1, 0)
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ef4e34/6).

Comment: In T-SQL, you can only do logic operations such as AND, OR and NOT on "boolean values". Direct comparison of "boolean values" is not possible.

Comment: @peter thanks. Not as neat, but fixed now.

Comment: That isn't going to optimize so nicely

Answer (score 3):

**A new option is now available in SQL Server 2022,** which has now implemented the ISO-standard [**`IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) syntax mentioned in the comments.

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM tab1 AS i
FULL OUTER JOIN tab2 AS d ON i.Id = d.Id
WHERE d.Data IS DISTINCT FROM i.Data;
```

This compiles into an `IS` comparison underneath (the same as in my other answer using `EXCEPT`), and is very efficient.