# T-SQL - Comparing two variables values with possible NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I am trying to write a T-SQL statement that will compare two nullable variables (either int or varchar), `@x` and `@y`, and return FALSE if both values are equal or both values are equal to NULL, and return TRUE otherwise. A and B are both placeholders for possible values.

```
+------+------+--------+
| @x   | @y   | Result |
+------+------+--------+
| NULL | NULL | False  |
| A    | A    | False  |
| B    | A    | True   |
| A    | B    | True   |
| NULL | A    | True   |
| A    | NULL | True   |
+------+------+--------+
```

I can use `COALESCE(@x,@y)` to verify that both `@x` and `@y` are NULL. Since no value can ever be equal to (or not equal to) NULL, I cannot use <> or = operators. What would be the most compact way to write such statement? Do I have to state a bunch of conditions, such as: `(@x is not NULL and @y is not null and @x <> @y)  or (@x is not null and @y is null) or (@x is null and @y is not null)`?

Comment: The answers below are fine when this is a select column in your query. But you probably want to stick to something like `(@x is not NULL and @y is not null and @x <> @y)` in a where clause to ensure sargability.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138082/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-a-null-compare-of-2-values) See [Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html) on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(10) = 'b',
        @y varchar(10) = 'a';


SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(@x,'') = COALESCE(@y,'') THEN 'FALSE'
            ELSE 'True'
       END AS Test
```

Note that you may want to choose some random value for `COALESCE(@x,'')`... Something that you'd never find in your data.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? FALSE when...

```
ISNULL(@x,'') = ISNULL(@y,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Coalesce` to check for two `NULL` values and `=` to check for equal non-NULL values: `not( Coalesce( @x, @y ) is NULL or @x = @y )`.

Note that the following code does not introduce a *magic value*, e.g. by using `Coalesce( A, '' )`, that must not occur in the data.

As Dale K. suggested, applying a function to a column in a `where` clause *generally* renders the condition [un-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

```
declare @Samples as Table ( X VarChar(1), Y VarChar(1) );
insert into @Samples ( X, Y ) values
  ( NULL, NULL ), ( 'A', 'A' ), ( 'B', 'A' ), ( 'A', 'B' ), ( NULL, 'A' ), ( 'A', NULL );

select X, Y,
  -- Note: The result values are flipped rather than including   not   in the condition.
  case when Coalesce( X, Y ) is NULL or X = Y then 'False' else 'True' end as Result
  from @Samples;
```

Demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60bbdcc75ec02524444c09cdc7a7908e).