# Entity Framework 6 and is null

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I would like to get all lines
from a table where column: CODEFIN (varchar) not like "MIR" or "CED".

*My table looks like this:*

| CODEFIN | ID |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 2 |
| NULL | 3 |
| MIR | 2 |

**My Entity Framwork linq request is**:

```
db.MYTABLE.Where(m => m.CODEFIN !="MIR" && m.CODEFIN != "CED") [...]
```

But CODEFIN null lines not appear...

I get the generated sql, but this is the same things in my sql editor.

the sql is like this:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CODEFIN] AS [CODEFIN],
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    FROM [dbo].[MYTABLE] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ('MIR' <> [Extent1].[CODEFIN] AND 'CED' <> [Extent1].[CODEFIN])
```

Thank you.
Sylvain

Comment: `NULL` is "special" in databases - the comparison `"foo" != NULL` is actually `false`.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it as

```
db.MYTABLE.Where(m => m.CODEFIN == NULL ||
    (m.CODEFIN !="MIR" && m.CODEFIN != "CED"))
```

or use `Contains`:

```
db.MYTABLE.Where(m => m.CODEFIN == NULL ||
    !(new [] {"MIR", "CED"}.Contains(m.CODEFIN)))
```

Which would yield the SQL:

```
WHERE [Extent1].[CODEFIN] IS NULL OR ([Extent1].[CODEFIN] NOT IN ('MIR', 'CED'))
```

Comparing something (even `NULL`) to `NULL` always yields `NULL`, not `FALSE`, and `NOT(NULL)` is still `NULL`, not `TRUE`, so you have to be more explicit about checking for nulls.

Comment: EF did not generate the "IS NULL" in sql with this solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
&& m.CODEFIN == null
```

Answer (score 0):

A sometimes more efficient solution is to use `Except`

```sql
db.MYTABLE.Where(m => new [] {"MIR", "CED"}
              .Except(new[] {m.CODEFIN})
              .Any())
```

This should hopefully result in the following SQL

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 'MIR'
    UNION
    SELECT 'CED'
    EXCEPT
    SELECT [Extent1].[CODEFIN]
)
```

This is pretty efficient, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139209/14868997).