# SQL Server Case Statement when IS NULL - Other SO questions do not solve this issue

Tags: sql-server, null, case

There are 2 questions on SO, but they are different and do not solve this problem. Feel free to test it before marking this as duplicate.

There is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/55e65/2) for this question.

In this example, the cell phone number may be NULL

| ID | Name | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 123 |
| 2 | Sally | NULL |

The query works when the cell number is not null:

```
DECLARE @Cell NVARCHAR(100) = '123'

SELECT * 
FROM Temp
WHERE Cell = CASE WHEN @Cell IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @Cell END
```

The same query fails when the cell number is null.

```
DECLARE @Cell NVARCHAR(100) = NULL

SELECT * 
FROM Temp
WHERE Cell = CASE WHEN @Cell IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @Cell END
```

The question is how to get the `CASE WHEN` working for both NULL and  when it is comparing an actual value. Note that this is a simplified example of the  real problem (which has a lot more conditions and additional complexity) and the focus is to get the example working by modifying the `CASE WHEN` in order to solve the real problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138082/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-a-null-compare-of-2-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` isn’t equal to anything, including `NULL` but you can just check if something is `NULL`

```
WHERE (@Cell IS NULL AND Cell IS NULL) OR Cell = @Cell
```

Probably could also move the comparison inside `CASE` but this is clear in meaning at least.

Comment: This has made me realise that I cannot use CASE WHEN when comparing against a NULL. I had to move it out of the CASE WHEN into the WHERE clause. If you do know how to kep it in the CASE WHEN please advise - it was not straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the `CASE` expression, with `COALESCE()`:

```
DECLARE @Cell NVARCHAR(100) = ?
Select * from Temp
WHERE Cell = @Cell OR COALESCE(Cell, @Cell) IS NULL;
```

Replace `?` with the value that you search for or `NULL`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0be820bffd52b488c502d5b7991a03fd).