# How to return rows that do not yet exist in another table without common ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL so please bear with me.

I have 2 tables:

Table1:

```
Col1    Col2     ColXX    ColYY     IsDisplay
---------------------------------------------
NULL      AA        NULL     AA         1
BBB       CCC       QQ       QQ         1
DDD       EEE       QQ       QQ         1
1F        2G        WW       WW         0
1H        1H        SS      NULL        1
```

Table2:

```
ID      Col1     Col2    Sold    Total    TotalPax
-------------------------------------------------------
1       BBB       CCC     10       10       1
1       DDD       EEE     10       10       1
1       1H        1H      5        50       10
1       NULL      AA      5        50       10
```

As you can see, in the 2 tables the only common columns are Col1 and Col2. Given that.

I need to get the unique data for ColXX and ColYY in table1 that are not present in table2. For this case:

```
     ColXX    ColYY   
    ----------------
     QQ       QQ    
     WW       WW
     SS       NULL
```

I don't know how to do it. Can somebody can help me? Thanks

Sample data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92640/15

Comment: can you explain why `QQ QQ` and `SS NULL` are in the expected result ?

Comment: Hi. :) It is because QQ , WW, SS is not present in table2

Comment: So your criteria is value in `Table1` `ColXX` and `ColYY` not exists in `Table2` `Col1` and `Col2` ?

Comment: @Squirrel yes. That is right.

Comment: have you tried using [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: So far, I have tried this: SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT Col1,Col2 
    FROM table2 
   ); but it returns 0 rows

Comment: add a `where` clause to the inner not exists query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table1   AS t1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM table2   AS t2
     WHERE (t2.Col1 = t1.ColXX OR (t2.Col1 IS NULL AND t1.ColXX IS NULL)) 
       AND (t2.Col2 = t1.ColYY OR (t2.Col2 IS NULL AND t1.ColYY IS NULL)) 
  )
```

Note, your fiddle/example has `Co11` instead of `Col1`?

Demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92640/12

Comment: Hi. Thanks, it works. I updated the sample sqlfidlle in the question. :)

Comment: @Amelia But do you understand why it works? Correlating subqueries is a fundamental skill in any version of SQL.

Comment: Side note: have you ever seen [this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139209/14868997) for comparing nulls?

Answer (score 3):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL`

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Taking a closer look to your data and you example I think you need this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColXX, ColYY
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON 
  ISNULL(t1.ColXX, '') = ISNULL(t2.Col1, '') 
  AND ISNULL(t1.ColYY, '') = ISNULL(t2.Col2, '')
WHERE ISNULL(t2.ID, '')=''
```

Comment: Thank You for your help, but it seems that upon running the query in sqlfiddle It only returns WW rows. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/92640/1

Comment: because in your fiddle you have used empty strings instead of NULLs

Comment: @mtwstark - the NULL vs '' isn't the cause. Its that the op wants to join on colXX and colYY, but the question doesn't make that very clear.

Comment: @MatBailie yeah :) I understood it after taking a closer look at the desired output