# Param string on Dapper in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm having troubles with my param string on my WHERE clause of my method. I'm trying to do a query like this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name @Filter OR Email @Filter";
```

And then inside my switch their cases will be like:

```
public async Task<List<DTO>>Get(FilterDTO filter)
{
    foreach(var f in filter.fields)
    {
        switch(f.Operator)
        {
            case 1:
                if(f.Value == null)
                {
                   f.Value = "IS NULL";
                   queryResult = connection.Query<Model>(query, new {Filter = f.Filter});
                   break;
                }
                else
                    goto case 2;
```

I'm having a lot of troubles with my param string because I cannot see what is failing on debug

[image]

Notice my real value name is `FilterValue` (this code it's a simplification)

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near @Filter

So I know something is wrong about my param string input but I cannot see what is it

Comment: What is `f.Value` and why you're not using in expression? I think you have missed something

Comment: I made a little edit, maybe it's more understandable now. For example, if my postman input is f.Value = null then I enter on the if condition, f.Value takes the string "IS NULL" and it goes into my query but then fails.

Comment: You *cannot* "parametrize" the operators - *only* the values..... so you cannot pass in an expression including an operator as a parameter value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138082/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-a-null-compare-of-2-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (@Filter is null and Email is null or @Filter = Email) 
                    OR    (@Filter is null and Name is null or @Filter = Name)
```

In that case you can set the parameter **Filter = null** and get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Dapper is using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE Name = IS NULL OR Email = IS NULL
```

which is invalid.

First create a profiler to see what query dapper is actually executing on the database (is easier to debug this situations - I recommend MiniProfiler lib).

Second, the `IS NULL` filter is meant to be on the query string OR use: `Name = NULL` rather than `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use parameters from Dapper like this.
To have a valid query you'd need to have

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name = @Filter OR Email = @Filter;
```

But that won't work with null.

You actually need to create the query, not just the parameters

```
const string query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name {0} OR Email {0}";
var result = conn.Query(string.Format(query, filterValue));
```

Edit:
If you can use Dapper.SqlBuilder you can build the query with Dapper as well.
Something like this:

```
var sqlBuilder = new SqlBuilder();
string myFilterValue = null;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myFilterValue))
{
    sqlBuilder.OrWhere("Name IS NULL").OrWhere("Email IS NULL");
}
else
{
    sqlBuilder.OrWhere("Name = @Filter", new { Filter = myFilterValue }).OrWhere("Email = @Filter", new { Filter = myFilterValue });
}
var template = sqlBuilder.AddTemplate("select * from table /**where**/");
using var conn = new SqlConnection("");
var result = conn.Query(template.RawSql, template.Parameters);
```