# Querying null datetime field with parameters

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table on my database (SQL Server 2016):

```
ID (numeric(10,0), not null)
Price (numeric(12,2), not null)
StartDate (datetime, null)
EndDate (datetime, null)
```

(There are more fields, but this is enough to get the point across)

One particular record has 'NULL' values for StartDate and EndDate:

```
ID        15
Price     25
StartDate NULL
EndDate   NULL
```

If I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
```

Then the record is return as expected

However the following query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = NULL
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = NULL
SELECT * FROM [Table] 
WHERE StartDate = @StartDate AND EndDate = @EndDate
```

I get no records!
What am I missing?

The following does work, but it just 'feels' wrong!

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = NULL
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = NULL
SELECT * FROM [Table] 
WHERE (StartDate = @StartDate OR (StartDate IS NULL AND @StartDate IS NULL))
  AND (EndDate   = @EndDate   OR (EndDate   IS NULL AND @EndDate   IS NULL))
```

For context, the query will ultimately be run via a VB.Net application, but I'm getting this problem running the query via SSMS, so it's definitely a SQL issue.

Comment: *"The following does work, but it just 'feels' wrong!"* But it's correct. `NULL` is an *unknown* value, and it doesn't equal (`=`) anything, *including* `NULL`. `NULL = NULL` returns *unknown* not *true*. The only way to compare a `NULL` value is with `IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: `where StartDate = null` will never be true, so if you have null values than you cannot do `where StartDate = @StartDate` because that will be `false` when at least one row is encountered with StartDate is null. So you need to check on null seperate, just like the query that feels wrong

Comment: @GuidoG , technically your statement *"because that will be `false`"* is incorrect. In that boolean expression if either `StartDate` or `@StartDate` are `NULL` then *unknown* would returned **not** *false*. Otherwise something like `NOT(StartDate = @StartDate)` (when either are `NULL`) would return *true*, which it would not (`NOT({UNKNOWN}) = UNKNOWN`). Often *unknown* and *false* are thought of being the same, as they *aren't* *true* (and so the row is not returned in this example), but they do still behave differently and they are distinctly different.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, gotta love NULLs!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to simplify a NULL compare of 2 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138082/is-there-a-way-to-simplify-a-null-compare-of-2-values)

Comment: You can do `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT StartDate INTERSECT SELECT @StartDate)`. Incidentally, both this and your existing code will optimize down to an `IS` comparison, rather than an `OR` expression or a correlated subquery