# Insert new records where one doesn't already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help inserting new data where it doesn't already exist.

Currently I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (column1, column2, column3, column4)
    SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4
    FROM dbo.staginTable
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Table AS A ON A.column1 = value1 
                             AND A.column2 = value2 
                             AND A.column3 = value3 
                             AND A.column4 = value4 
    WHERE A.column1 IS NULL 
      AND A.column2 IS NULL 
      AND A.column3 IS NULL 
      AND A.column4 IS NULL
```

This query works fine and doesn't insert data which already exists in the **dbo.Table** if none of the variables **(value1, value2, value3, value4)** is null.

My problem is that it`s very common that e.g. either value3 or value4 or both can be null and in this case the values will be inserted

**Works:**

```
(value1, value2, value3, value4)
('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
(value1, value2, value3, value4)
('one', 'two', NULL, 'four')
```

I know that I could add a Unique index on the 4 columns to bypass this problem or I could use another query like *insert expect* but I would like to know if it's possible to use the query above or what I need to change in the query.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like you need to be using an `exists` correlation.

Comment: check table for NOT NULL Constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that the columns you are comparing are all nullable, `EXCEPT` can be a more compact form

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (column1, column2, column3, column4)
SELECT ST.value1, ST.value2, ST.value3, ST.value4
    FROM dbo.StagingTable ST
EXCEPT
SELECT MT.value1, MT.value2, MT.value3, MT.value4
    FROM dbo.MyTable MT;
```

Alternatively, you can do it in a correlated subquery, this is especially useful if other columns are involved that are not being compared

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
    SELECT ST.value1, ST.value2, ST.value3, ST.value4, ST.value5
    FROM dbo.StagingTable ST
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT ST.value1, ST.value2, ST.value3, ST.value4
      INTERSECT
      SELECT MT.value1, MT.value2, MT.value3, MT.value4
      FROM dbo.MyTable MT
    );
```

Fear not: this subquery is [completely elided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66139209/14868997) by the compiler

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using `NOT EXISTS`- because that makes logical sense. Then you need to combine your `NULL` compares with value compares as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (column1, column2, column3, column4)
    SELECT value1, value2, value3, value4
    FROM dbo.StagingTable ST
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM dbo.MyTable MT
      WHERE (ST.value1 = MT.value1 OR (ST.value1 IS NULL AND MT.value1 IS NULL))
      AND (ST.value2 = MT.value2 OR (ST.value2 IS NULL AND MT.value2 IS NULL))
      AND (ST.value3 = MT.value3 OR (ST.value3 IS NULL AND MT.value3 IS NULL))
      AND (ST.value4 = MT.value4 OR (ST.value4 IS NULL AND MT.value4 IS NULL))
    );
```